# Doubt related to finding the gcd between two elements of an euclidian domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification

This is a pretty elementary doubt, I assume, but anyway:

**The doubt.** Let's say we want to find $gcd(a,b)$, where $a,b \in D$, where $D$ represents an eucilidain domain. Can we use rests and quotients that are NOT in $D$? I leave a pratical example below.

**Pratical Example.** Let's say we are working on $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$. Determine $gcd(x^3+x,x^2+x)$.

**What I've done.** As $dg(x^3+x) > dg(x^2+x)$ (where $dg$ stands for degree) we proceed the following way:

[image]

And so the answer would be $\widetilde{\frac{1}{2}(x+1)} = \widetilde{x+1} \in Z_2[x]$. My question is basically why is this computation not right. My guess is that I messed up by not using some elements NOT in $Z_2[x]$ during the process but I would like more details on it. Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Hint: so you have $x^3+x=(x^2+x)(x-1)+2x$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ (I guess that you're calling $\mathbb{Z}_2$ the finite field with two elements and not the $2$-adics). But $2x=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ so $x^3+x=(x^2+x)(x-1)$.

Comment: @Mindlack I understand it, thanks! Just to confirm my point tough: Can I use quotients and rests that ARE NOT in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ ? By this I mean, for example, is it okay to use $x-1$ as a quotient in the first division altough $x-1 \notin \mathbb{F}_2[x]$ ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you think that $x-1\not\in \Bbb F_2[x]$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I tought $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ standed for all polynomials with coefficients either $0$ or $1$ and since we have the constant $-1$ I assumed it wasn't in $\mathbb{F}_2[x].$ Is my thinking wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong, because the coefficient $-1=1$ in $\Bbb F_2$. So $x+1=x-1=-x-1=-x+1=3x+3=5x+5$ and so on, are all the same polynomial in $\Bbb F_2[x]$.

Comment: So basically I can transform any polynomial in a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ iff all its coefficients are integers? (negative or positive)

Comment: But your concern is valid in the 2nd case since $2=0$ in $\Bbb Z_2$ so $2$ is not invertible, so $1/2$ makes no sense.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant in my last comment @BillDubuque , Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @DietrichBurde . Really clarifying. I think I got it all now!

Comment: The accepted answers doesn't address the heart of your misunderstanding. It would be better to unaccept. Then maybe someone else will have the time to explain more carefully (that is not the purpose of comments). It is almost always a bad idea to accept quickly. Many users skip questions with accepted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ you have $2x=0x=0$, so the first division leaves no remainder.

Comment: How would one describe $\mathbb{Z_2}$ then? I thought it standed for the elements $0$ and $1$. This implies (e.g) $2=0$,$3=1$,$4=0$ and so on, in $\mathbb{Z_2}$ ? Thanks for the help once again!

Comment: You can do that, or avoid it using the operations **as defined in** $\Bbb Z_2$. Look carefully: how did you get a $2$ and got outside of $\Bbb Z_2$? By adding $1+1$, but $1+1=0$ in $\Bbb Z_2$

Comment: Makes sense... Thanks for the help! Can you have a look at my answer to @Mindlack comment? Thanks once again!